# Info on Web Application Compilation Model vs Web Site model

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone please give me a nice, expert but concise summary the ASP.NET compilation model with the older, code-behind style, web applications?

I'm fairly familiar with the newer web *site* model, using partial classes and on-demand compilation, but I'm curious as to how ASP.NET marries the front-deployed ASPX pages to the pre-compiled code behind.  Does it still do on-demand compilation of the ASPX's, but reference code behind, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code-behind acted as a base class. The aspx part could still have on-demand compilation.
The codebehind classes where compiled to a dll.

Comment: What do you mean with 'could have on demand compilation?  Can web applications also be pre-compiled like web sites?  That is the only scenario I see where no on-demand compilation would take place, except for .aspx with no server tags.

Comment: yes, they can be pre-compiled, when you do that the aspx on the deployed version are pretty much empty place holders (one line).